# Pass 3D array through parameter, perform operation and return in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, embedded, vivado

I'm attempting to pass a 3D array stored in my PYNQ boards Direct Memory Access, perform a simple function and return as an output back to the DMA. Here is the function I currently have:

```
#include <ap_int.h>

#define BLOCKS 4
#define LENGTH 8


void multiplyArray(volatile ap_uint<32> * input[BLOCKS][LENGTH][LENGTH], volatile ap_uint<32> * output[BLOCKS][LENGTH][LENGTH]){

    #pragma HLS INTERFACE axis PORT = input
    #pragma HLS INTERFACE axis PORT = output

    int x;
    int j;
    int i;

    for(x = 0; x < BLOCKS; x++){

        for(j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++){

            for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){

                output[x][j][i] = input[x][j][i] + 1;
            }

        }

    }
```

It is returning multiple errors including unsupported memory access on input, "output[x][j][i] = input[x][j][i] + 1;" has both read and write, and input cannot be set to the axis. Very new to this and would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: `ap_uint<32> * input[BLOCKS][LENGTH][LENGTH]` are you sure about the `*` there? Try removing it, and the same for `output`.

Comment: ok that solved a lot of the errors thanks! still one on this line "output[x][j][i] = input[x][j][i] + 1;" but it does not specify why..

Comment: I removed the volatile from the input and it seems to be working

Comment: Are you sure you want to be coping the parameters? I'd say you need to pass a reference `&`

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Change `*` to `&` otherwise you're just passing copies to the array and the result is not going to be propagated back to the callee

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu What are you talking about? The OP should use use `*` if it is an array of pointers, which doesn't seem to be the case. Otherwise neither `*` nor `&`. Passing raw arrays by reference doesn't make much sense because of the rule of array decay.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, this part `volatile ap_uint<32> *` needs to correspond to the array item type. If the array is a 3D array of type `ap_uint<32>` then the parameter should be `ap_uint<32> input[BLOCKS][LENGTH][LENGTH]`. Example:

```
void multiplyArray (ap_uint<32> input  [BLOCKS][LENGTH][LENGTH], 
                    ap_uint<32> output [BLOCKS][LENGTH][LENGTH]);
```